# Error connecting SwiftUI 2.0 app to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

When I try to initialise a Firebase app, the output `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed` is produced.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import PartialSheet
import Firebase

@main
struct Food_DeliveryApp: App {
    
    var cart = Cart()
    var sheetManager = PartialSheetManager()
    var settings = SheetManager()
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LoginPageView()
                .environmentObject(sheetManager)
                .environmentObject(settings.setManager(manager: sheetManager))
                .environmentObject(cart)
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

It looks like it launches `FirebaseApp.configure()`, but can't find GoogleService-info.plist or something.

Comment: Can you add the first few lines from your log to your question? Also, if it’s missing the GoogleService-Info.plist file, make sure it’s included in the build target.

Comment: @PeterFriese `2020-10-05 16:06:45.343605+0300 Food Delivery[9077:169592] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
`. This is all. Also, I've checked that GoogleService-info.plist is included in the build target.

Comment: Hm - I was hoping to see some sort of message that says why I didn't find the `GoogleService-info.plist` file...